# Is there a standard dialog for constructing an ADO.Net connection string (that is redistributable)?

Tags: ado.net, dialog, connection-string

I want to use a standard dialog to solicit user input of an ADO.net connection string.  It is trivial to do for the oledb connection string as described here:
[MSDN Article on MSDASC.DataLinks().Prompt](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;310083)

I've also found examples that use Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.dll and MicrosoftData.ConnectionUI.Dialog.dll from VS ([HOWTO: Using the Choose Data Source dialog of Visual Studio 2005 from your own code](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/mz2007011.aspx)).

Unfortunately these DLLs are not licensed for redistribution.

Is there a standard dialog for choosing a data source that can be distributed with my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a free "Add Connection" or "SQL Connection" Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567981/is-there-a-free-add-connection-or-sql-connection-dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for these DLLs is now available: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2010/02/02/data-connection-dialog-source-code-is-released-on-code-gallery.aspx

Also you can do this programmatically using the DataLink Properties:

**Add the reference to ADODB.DLL (from .NET reference) and Microsoft OLE DB Service Component 1.0 Type Library from the COM tab in your visual studio reference tab.**

```
using ADODB;
using Microsoft.Win32;
public partial class ConnectionStringStep : Form
    {
        private const string MSSQL_PROVIDER = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1";

        private const string ORACLE_PROVIDER = "Provider=MSDAORA.1";

        private const string MSSQL = "MSSQL";

        public ConnectionStringStep()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private static string DataBaseType()
        {
            //get the data from some previous screen or some kind of storage
            return MyStorage.GetProperty("DATABASE_TYPE") ?? "MSSQL";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dataBaseType = DataBaseType();

            var adodbConnection = new Connection
                                      {
                                          ConnectionString = dataBaseType == MSSQL ? MSSQL_PROVIDER : ORACLE_PROVIDER
                                      };

            object connection = (object) adodbConnection;

            var dialog = new MSDASC.DataLinks();

            dialog.PromptEdit(ref connection);

            connectionTextBox.Text = adodbConnection.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
```

[DataLink Properties Reference](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/2011/07/20/building-an-installer-and-displaying-data-link-properties-dialog-box-for-connection-string/)

Answer (score 3):

@rathkopf, it looks like these DLLs have been authorized for redistribution since Feb 2010:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/423104/redistributable-microsoft-data-connectionui-dll-and-microsoft-data-connectionui-dialog-dll

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the 1st link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a NuGet package by Microsoft providing this dialog:

[DataConnectionDialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog).

Sample usage:

```
var dialog = new DataConnectionDialog();
dialog.DataSources.Add(DataSource.SqlDataSource);
dialog.ConnectionString = connectionString;

if (DataConnectionDialog.Show(dialog) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    connectionString = dialog.ConnectionString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's related, but I'm now sure how you can embed this behavior inside your application.

Every time I need one, I create an empty text file, changed its file extension to ".udl" and double-click it; when I'm done, I close that application, rename that file back to ".txt" and open with Notepad.

Comment: thats how i do it too, except I create it programmatically. It's not that easy though, you have to set some custom but in the beginning.

This technique is "distibutable", at least on Windows systems.

Comment: Seems this gives the same OLE DB provider, not the ADO.Net provider.

Comment: See my answer if you want to know how to **programmatically** do the `UDL` file trick:)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that such a beast does not exist.  I've written my own dialog and can include it in projects as needed.

---

**Update:**

The source code for these DLLs are now available as per @code4life's answer.