# SQL Login screen in WPF?

Tags: sql, wpf, authentication, screen

I have a question.
Is it possible to prompt a SQL Login screen(the one that comes up when you start SQL Server) in a WPF application ?

Comment: You mean "the one that comes up when you start SQL Server **Management Studio**" right? Starting SQL Server usually happens without a user interface...

Comment: You just want login screen or do you want to start sqlserver management studio from WPF..?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the login dialog that shows up when starting SQL Management Studio.

Have a look at this question: [Is there a free "Add Connection" or "SQL Connection" Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567981/is-there-a-free-add-connection-or-sql-connection-dialog)

This does not answer your question on WPF but might help you. As far as I know there is no WPF version of these dialogs.